# Consecutive chars in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add consecutive chars using a loop in a list like `s=['A','B','C']`.
I want to use a loop to insert chars as we do with ints.

I tried

```
s='A'
sim=[1]*3
for i in range(0,3):
    sim.append(s)
    s+=1
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for uppercase chars: `'A' = 65`, `'B' = 66` ... `'Z' = 90`

similarly for lowercase chars: `'a' = 97`, `'b' = 98` ... `'z' = 122`

you can convert integers to chars by using `chr()` and in reverse, convert chars to integers by using `ord()`. see [this link](https://realpython.com/python-strings/#built-in-string-functions)

some examples:

```
>>> chr(67)
'C'
>>> ord('A')
65
>>> chr(ord('A') + 1)
'B'
```

in your case:

```
s = []
for i in range(26):
    s.append(chr(ord('A')+i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `string` module (which is shipped together with Python) for that task following way:

```
import string
s = []
for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
    s.append(letter)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

If you want lowercase just replace `string.ascii_uppercase` with `string.ascii_lowercase`